# Increment constant in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose, in Excel, I have a formula `=$C$8+1`, what must I add to the 1 such that when I drag, it becomes `$C$8+2`?

Can this be done?

Below is my actual formula.. I wish to increment 1 to 2 such that it becomes =2

```
IF((NOW()-$C8)=1,"1","0")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well.. there might be several ways to do it, but the only one I have in the top of my head is using the `=ROW()` function.

Let's say you're starting the formula at row 5.

`=IF((NOW()-$C8)=ROW()-4,"1","0")`

The =ROW() will return the row number you currently are (i.e. 5, in this case). Thus, in the first row we'll have =1 (from 5-4) and then =2 (6-4) and so on.

Still, it seems you're comparing dates, right? I'd say you'd need to truncate the values to have a day comparison between them...

`=IF((TRUNC(NOW())-TRUNC($C8))=ROW()-4,"1","0")`

Hope it helps... or at least give you a path to chose your solution.

Comment: The row idea is clever. Nice!